# How to use many jar files?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, executable-jar

Is it possible to use a class from another jar instead of the main one ?

My working directory:

```
.
|-- Main.java
|-- Makefile
|-- Manifest
`-- original
    `-- Test.java
```

`Main.java`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
       Test.test();
    }
}
```

`Test.java`:

```
public class Test {
    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("This is a test");
    }
}
```

`Manifest`:

```
Main-Class: Main
```

So, I do:

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath original/:./ Main.java
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath original/:./ original/Test.java
```

And it generates `Main.class and original/Test.class`
I can run it with `java -classpath original/:./ Main`. That's what I want.

But now I need `jar` files. How to do it correctly ?

I tried:

```
jar cfm Main.jar Manifest Main.class
jar cfm original/Test.Jar Manifest original/Test.class
```

But here I don't know how to run my `Main` properly.

If I do: `java -jar -classpath original/:./ Main`.

I got `Error: unable to access jarfile Main`.

And if I do: `java -jar original/Test.jar Main.jar`.

I got `Error: could not find or load main class Main`.

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just noticed, your Test.java file is in original folder, hence you need to declare package original; in top so your Test.java file should be like,

```
package original;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Hello Test");
    }
}
```

Then you need to compile both Main.java and original\Test.java by following command,

```
javac Main.java original\Test.java
```

Then run this command to create your jar file,

```
jar cf main.jar Main.class original\Test.class
```

This will create main.jar file and then you can run following commands to either run Main or Test programs,

```
java -cp main.jar Main
```

or

```
java -cp main.jar original.Test
```

Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: But here is my problem, `java -cp Main.jar Main` gives me a `ClassNotFoundException`. I need two `jar` files and "link" them dynamically.

Comment: ok I just noticed, your Test.java file is in original folder, so you have to declare package original; in your Test.java file

Comment: And now I have `second/Test.java` withe the same prototype.
How can I change the behaviour of my program, without changing `Main.java` and `Main.jar` but just changing the classpath ?
It is possible with `.class` files like this: `java -classpath original/:./ Main` and `java -classpath second/:./ Main`

Comment: No issues, just like original\Test.java you need to declare "package second;" in top of second/Test.java file and follow rest just like original/Test.java and while running command to run, you will have to write, java -cp main.jar second.Test

Answer (score 0):

This should be a point, where you should start using Maven, or Gradle to build your application.

This way, you can include the external libraries in your built .jar file, and you don't need to worry nearly as much about choosing the right .jar dependency

Comment: I'll recommend a beginner java programmer to go through those basic commands for sometime, so they get to know some internals also as to how the program gets compiled and run in case they have to do such things on some remote machines where they can't use fancy IDEs for some reason.

Comment: Btw my commands are in Makefile, I'm not using any IDE and I don't want to.

Comment: maven does not require an IDE. For a test project, you might want to try the commands sometimes, I agree with that

Answer (score 0):

I run next:

- Compile classes

  `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -classpath original/:./ original/Test.java
  javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6  Main.java`
- Create the jar

  `jar cfe app.jar Main Main.class original/Test.class`
- Run the jar

  `java -jar app.jar`

  Output: `This is a test`